# Drupal 7: displaying array variables with its links in node.tpl.php

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm building a single user blog with Drupal 7. I use Article content type as blog entry. I need to customize the look of node. I also added a taxonomy field to article refering category. and I need to display this and tags in my node at a particular place.

So, I wrote the code **dpm(get_defined_vars());** and get the variables (shown below)

but how can I display these variables in my **node--article.tpl.php** with links to a page lists other article entries have these tags, categories? These are array and I need to display each array item with links :/

[image]

Appreciate helps!!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow

```
<?php
  $links = array();
  foreach ($node->field_tags AS $term) {
    $links[] = l($term['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/'. $term['tid']);
  }
  print implode(', ', $links) .'<br />';

  $links = array();
  foreach ($node->field_blog_post_category['und'] AS $term) {
    $links[] = l($term['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/'. $term['tid']);
  }
  print implode(', ', $links);
?>
```